# Read excel from GCP storage bucket via python

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am facing this error message when I do simple pd.read_excel() in python to read an excel file from storage.

```
AttributeError: 'ClientSession' object has no attribute '_connector'
at closed (/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py:963)
at __del__ (/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py:326)
```

I have tried various versions of pandas library - locally it works fine but when I deploy it to Google Cloud Function, I get the above error. I am not sure why this error is happening?

Any idea? I have been stuck on this for ages and exhausted my options.
Thank you.

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal reproducible example (minimal Cloud Function code + requirements.txt) ?

Comment: This might answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/66379502/14733669